# Archaeological alphametic

Tags: no-computers, alphametic

Enigmarchaeologists uncovered an ancient Roman precursor to our familiar,
and comparatively dignified,  
SEND + MORE = MONEY 
[alphametic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verbal_arithmetic).

> **TEE + HEE + HEE + HO + HO + HEH + OH + ME + OH + MY + HMM
>       =  
>     OH + HEY + AHA**

**What is that equation in substituted
  [*Roman* numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals)?**

And just for giggles, what does  
**TEE + HEE** 
by itself equal with the same substitutions?

Each letter— A, E, H, M, O, T and Y—stands
for a different
Roman digit—  I, V, X, L, C, D or M — in
a correspondence to be deduced.
 
Only standard Roman numerals are in play, not
[alternative
  forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals#Alternative_forms).

For example . . .

. . . If the puzzle were  
GIN + FIG   =   FUN,   its letters *could* be
                                            substituted to become  
XLV + DLX   =   DCV,   which amounts to  
45 + 560 = 605   in Arabic numerals.

```
             Example        Substitutions        Roman               Arabic
                             F   -->   D
                GIN          U   -->   C           XLV                   45
              + FIG          I   -->   L         + DLX       =        + 560
             -------         G   -->   X        -------              -------
                FUN          N   -->   V           DCV                  605
```

Comment: are they all valid roman numerals? for example. CDC is not valid.

Comment: maybe you should add that to the question to avoid confusion.

Comment: Just to be pedantic, currently the incorrect `IXC` is allowed but the correct `XCIX` is not.

Comment: Thanks for nudges, Marius and @Boboquack, they even helped me catch an omission in the instructions. Guess I'll just refer to the Wikipedia page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> E and M are doubled with a letter on front and can therefore be just I and X. Suppose E = I, M = X. Then we have HEH, which makes it impossible already - XIX would work, but M is X already.

So

> E is X (and M is I), and then H needs to be C to have a valid HEH. (LXL is not valid). This means A needs to be M to have valid AHA (MCM). HO would then need to be CD as there is no other option. MY requires Y to be V. Which leads to a single remaining letter for T = L.

Lets substitute back:

> LXX + CXX + CXX + CD + CD + CXC + DC + IX + DC + IV + CII   =   DC + CXV + MCM. 70 + 120 + 120 + 400 + 400 + 190 + 600 + 9 + 600 + 4 + 102 = 600 + 115 + 1900. 2615 = 2615

Looks good. Now the TEE+HEE part:

> TEE + HEE = LXX + CXX = 70 + 120 = 190 = CXC = HEH